# Include external scripts in Powershell executable

Tags: powershell, compilation

I wrote a Powershell script, and I call some functions from external scripts using Dot sourcing. The scripts I try to call are not detected after making the main script executable. Do I have to compile the scripts to be called as well?

Comment: **Include** the scripts in the main script and compile the whole thing

Comment: How should i do? Writing everything in one file?

Comment: Yep, I guess that's the best way..

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59288784/45375) helps.

Comment: I merged everything into one file. The solution proposed in the link of mklement0 is interesting, but in my case I don't have to execute scripts in sequence, and I need to pass parameters to the functions. Thanks a lot to everyone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to include another powershell script file inside of another powershell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65149351/how-to-include-another-powershell-script-file-inside-of-another-powershell-scrip)